# How to represent a localized string type in Core Data?

Tags: macos, core-data

I'm new to Core Data, and am struggling with some of it conceptually (relative to, say, SQL, which I understand).

I'm trying to build a model which for the sake of simplicity looks like:

```
"Category" entity, which has a name, and a relationship to-many Products
"Product" entity, which has a name
```

I want those `name`s (string) in both entities to store localized variants. That implies another join. There are a small number of possible localizations. I know that I could put each localization as an individual attribute ("name_en", "name_de", etc), but that doesn't scale, and I want to understand the "right" way of accomplishing this.

My gut tells me I want two more entities here, a Localizations one (which simply contains the set of possible localizations) and some sort of LocalizedString one, which related to the Localization. But Xcode warns me about not having Inverse relationships set up, etc.

Can someone who groks Core Data model design deeply please help out a newbie understand how to think through this problem?

(My next problem will be building the weirdly multi-pivoted UI that lets you set the name for each localization that's available, but that will be another set of investigation. :) )

Comment: Are these strings being entered by users or are they only used by the application? If you are using Core Data as backend for localizing your app then you would be better off using the localization tools provided. Otherwise I would tend to agree with fluchtpunkt's answer.

Comment: @sosborn: Entered by users. I would otherwise definitely agree with your advice in this case. (And this also seemed like a good learning example since the entity relationship is more interesting than in the CD tutorials I've gone through.) Thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I don't know if I qualify as somebody who groks core data but I've used something like this in the past:
[image]

`name` in `Something` is the english name. So I don't have to search the relationship in english language devices (which covers 70% of the devices for my app).
And there is a getter called `localizedName` in the `Something` subclass that either returns name or the string for the currently used language code.

When I did this I thought that I could save the localized string in the name property because languages usually don't change often on devices that are not used by developers. But finally I decided against this because that wasn't a performance problem.

Another variant I thought I could use to fight against non-existing performance problems:
[image]

currentLanguageString basically points to the localized string of the current language. It is changed everytime the language changes (in 99.9% of all cases this happens one time, when the app is first launched).

---

if you have more than one string in the `Something` entity I would make `LocalizedString` an abstract parent class of subclasses specifically created for the string you want to localize.
You have to use such strange constructs because you can't create a relationship to more than one entity.

[image]

---

Or if you know what you are doing, ignore the "no inverse relationship" warning

[image]

but if you go this way you have to make sure that you never delete a `LocalizedString` object that is still in use. You don't want to end with an inconsistent storage.

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed response. Good stuff. It's your very last point that interests me most. In SQL that LocalizedString table might be a tuple like (stringID, languageCode, text), but as you say, that sort of no-inverse generic storage isn't natural here. I'll think about it in the way you describe. Thx.

Comment: This can make your database enormous if you have many strings. Searching is also quite difficult/slow but otherwise it works