# How to localized data in Core Data

Tags: core-data, localization, internationalization

My app has pre-populate Category data contain icon image and its name. In the next version I need to localized its name, is this possible ? Found [Adding relation for localized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5534681/how-to-represent-a-localized-string-type-in-core-data) methods here, but this is an only way to do it ?

Answer (score 1):

There is no "Localize" feature build in to Core Data. So adding the localized names in a separate entity as mentioned in [How to represent a localized string type in Core Data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5534681/how-to-represent-a-localized-string-type-in-core-data) is the way to go.