# translations in core data

Tags: iphone, core-data, translation

I have an app that is providing a large set of reference terms and their translations in several languages. As far as we know, this is the only such "dictionary" of these terms available. Consequently, management are very keen to keep this data secure from hackers (one of our current apps has been breached and copied before).

Following that background, I don't want to simply put the translations into strings files like normal ([or else!!](http://thejoysofcode.com/post/38234612725/when-i-must-tell-my-boss-i-have-released-a-bug-in)). I'm pretty sure I won't be able to use NSLocalizedString any more? So I am thinking of putting the strings into a core data seed file that we will release with the app. The secure strings will be transformable using a CommonCrypto based NSValueTransformer.

**My question is how to manage a core data entity that as a property that can have multiple translations like this?**

For example, say entity `Car` has a property `modelName`, and `modelName` has various translations. What is the best way to store this kind of relationship?

NB: I have done a similar thing which had one sqlite file for each language and when the user switched language, the core data persistent store changed. But this won't work very smoothly in this app (I think, multiple MOCs maybe?)because we need several translations available at the same time.

Comment: Probably best answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5534681/how-to-represent-a-localized-string-type-in-core-data)