# IOS app internazionalization - Internazionalize DB Content

Tags: ios, objective-c, multilingual

Hi I would like to have some suggestion about the internazionalization of my app:

let's consider the app uses a DB to retrieve a set of question to propose to the user. Such questions should be translated in different languages.

I have considered two approaches:

1. One DB with the Table "Question". The table contains a column for each language I would like to support. (I dislike this approach since in the case i want to add in future new languages i should modify something already working)
2. More DB schema. Each DB schema is dedicated to a language seem better approach

Do you have any experience about the best solution to adopt? 
do you have any other solution to suggest?

Thank you and kind regards

Comment: Have a look at Localization and NSLocalizedString

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, could you be more specific? i'm talking about internationalizing DB content

Comment: http://nshipster.com/nslocalizedstring/

Comment: Thank you again for your suggestion however the website you suggested me (like most of the links i have found) talk about how to internationalize a string. In my situation i have a DB containing more than 1k question in a language. i think there should be another solution to internationalize directly the DB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really want to keep the questions in a DB, I would recommend only storing keys used by **NSLocalizedString** macro, and the actual translations in dedicated localisation files (*.string*) - as @Adam Richardson suggested. This way you can update the individual translations (or add new ones) without touching the DB itself.

Comment: Thank you Peter, i'll try to figure out your suggestion and the one of Adam. It seems a little strange to me to use a file to store such amount of data i thought this approach could be used just for simple translation (e.g. strings in the nib files). Thank you again

Comment: It all depends on particular implementation details - how many strings you need translated?

Comment: we are speaking of more than 1k strings

Comment: I'd still go with NSLocalizedString. The files may get a little unwieldy but nothing too bad, and you can use existing architecture to your advantage, instead of rolling your own custom solution.

Answer (score 0):

Hi due to a deeper research i have found this topic [How to represent a localized string type in Core Data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5534681/how-to-represent-a-localized-string-type-in-core-data) i'm going to adopt the tecnique suggested as a solution.

kind regards

Nicolò